# It or Him when talking about Regime

Tags: pronouns, gender

I heard in the media:

> Russia was behind the Syrian regime since day one: arming him,...

I am confused if I should refer to regime as it or him or her.

What about other words like machine, country, nation.. when can we use he or she for referring to them?

Comment: We use *it* for almost all nouns which do not have 'natural' gender.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in doubt, if it's not a gendered, living thing, refer to it as "it".

For your specific example:

> Russia was behind the Syrian regime since day one: arming **it**,...

That being said, if it said

> Putin was behind Assad's Syrian regime since day one, sending "him"...

In this case, with the addition of Assad, it's ok to use "him".

We do use gendered pronouns with some things **occasionally** but it's not required.

For example, some refer to ships and cars as "she"... but you won't hurt any feelings by calling a ship or car an "it".

Comment: In the example given, the word Syria is offered, but the "him"contextually refers to Assad.  The way of writing it implies that the regime and the leader are interchangeable, that's a deliberate way of framing a political ideology.  (doesn't matter whether Assad and "the regime" actually are interchangeable...the language is suggesting it.)

Comment: @dwoz if that's the case, there's some context missing from the question. As it stands, "him" is not really appropriate in my mind.

Comment: To add to the list of occasionally gendered things, countries are often referred to as female.  There are a few exceptions to this (and curiously they are usually the countries cast as villains in Western cinema).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, in general all the things that are not humans they get "it" (including pets).

Comment: A human female would not be called "it"...

Comment: I wrote "are not", look at this again please.

Comment: Your original said "are not pets". It has been edited since I commented.

Comment: Definitely not. You can see the history of the edition, if there is. You just suspect me for nothing. I'm sorry.

Comment: (cc @Catija) Assiduous, your original was quite wrong, although it seemed clear what you'd *meant* to say, which is what I fixed it to. (The [revision history](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/68776/revisions) is not ambiguous on when and why the change happened.)