# Which pronoun should be used for the country Germany in a tag question?

Tags: personal-pronouns, tag-questions

What will be the tag question of the following sentence?

> Germany is a beautiful country, isn't {she/he}?

Shouldn't we use the pronoun "she" as country is always considered as motherland? But one of my friend told me that we have to use "he" for Germany only as this country is considered as fatherland.

Comment: Countries _sometimes_ used to be personified as 'she' - **Britain was defending her interests** - but this is old-fashioned and certainly would not be used in everyday conversation.

Comment: The [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Pronouns/faq0015.html) says that if you use a pronoun other than *it* for a country, "you’ll sound as if you either don’t know English or last studied it in 1950."

Comment: Related questions: [Feminine pronouns for countries](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/103229/9161), [It or Him when talking about Regime](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68759/9161)

Answer (score 1):

We usually use **it** for countries.

> Germany is a beautiful country, isn't **it**?

The pronoun you use is exactly the same pronoun as you'd use for referring to Germany (or any other country) anywhere else - it isn't specific to question tags, nor to Germany.

In some (mainly older) books, **she** is used for countries, e.g. "61 percent of those polled still felt America wanted to save West Germany and **her** Western European neighbors from communism" (Dewey Browder, *Americans in Post-WWII Germany*, 1998).  This is a literary usage and may be seen as old-fashioned.

We would never use **he**.

Comment: Using the feminine pronouns for countries is old fashioned but not necessarily wrong. Would you agree though that using the masculine would mark the writer as a non-native English speaker?

Comment: @ColleenV I agree with all of that, so I've revised my answer slightly.